# How to maintain common space between two variables in whole column while creating excel file using pandas module

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am creating excel file using one excel file as input by using pandas module in python.the created excel file has one column that is signal name so it contain names of signals and followed by signal size and the space between signal name and size is varied from row to row in signal name column.so I want common space between signal name and size.

[image: the following image contain view of signal name column.]

I used following lines of code but it won't worked

```
Signal_Names = df['Signal Name'].tolist()
Signal_Size = df['Signal Size'].tolist()
for name,size, in zip(Signal_Names,Signal_Size,):
    data = "{0:20}{1:10}".format(name.ljust(40,' '),size)
```

Comment: We don't put text and data in the same column, because you can hardly use the data in calculations then. Use two columns instead.

Comment: Otherwise you need a non-proportional font, like Consolas or Courier

Comment: Thomas Weller, changing font did the trick for me.Thanks for the help.

Comment: Nah, don't change the font. Make it 2 columns: signal name and signal value

Answer (score 0):

```
   workbook  = writer.book
   worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
   format1 = workbook.add_format({"font_name": "Courier New"})
   worksheet.set_column('A:Z', None, format1)
   worksheet.set_row(0, None, format1)
   writer.save()
```